# String to ASCII 0 - xquery

Tags: xml, xslt, xquery, osb

I have a requirement to convert string to ASCII 0 . input:

```
'\0'
```

I'm developing in xquery 1.0.

I didn't found a way to do so with special characters. 
Thanks

Comment: The null character is not allowed in XQuery strings. End of story.

Comment: Hi I need to convert two characters '/0' . not null

Comment: Do you want to have *two characters* (the backslash, and the digit zero) or do you want the *special character* `\0`? You can have `'\'` and `'0'`. You can't have `\0`.

Comment: I can have '\' and '0'

Comment: Yes. But you can't have `ASCII 0`. I'm running out of ways to say it.